# Covert from Word to PDF via MS office on the command-line

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, ms-word, electron

I'm developing an Electron app and would like the end-users to be able to import a Word document and convert it to a PDF. Is there a way to do this via the command-line with MS Word on Windows and macOS?

I've found solutions that covert using [LibreOffice](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libreconv) or do `doc -> HTML -> pdf` such as [docx-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-pdf) style conversion. Of course there are API solutions but this is a no-go due to sensitive documents.

The requirement is to convert without a change of formatting, so the thinking is using MS Word to covert would minimise chances of changes (unlike docx-pdf) but also something the end-users are more likely to have installed (LibreOffice is very niche in this sector).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the docx2pdf tool to convert a docx file to pdf retaining all formatting. It works on macOS and Windows and requires Microsoft Word to be installed.

```
pip install docx2pdf
docx2pdf input.docx output.pdf
docx2pdf --help
```

If you don't want the python dependency, you can see the JXA (AppleScript for javascript) [code](https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf/blob/master/docx2pdf/convert.jxa) that can be directly run on macOS with no dependencies. It also uses win32com on windows to directly talk to Microsoft Word.

Disclaimer: I wrote the docx2pdf to pdf tool. https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf/

Comment: Al Johri, I'm trying to use your module but it is not working for me. Could you check [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62636726/why-is-the-docx2pdf-module-not-converting-docx-to-pdf-in-my-python-script-mac-os) to see whether you know what I should change for it to work? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to generate Microsoft word/excel/PowerPoint document dynamically .
Do check 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/officegen

Comment: The solution I'm looking for needs to generate a PDF from a Word document, that package only looks to create an Office document from input (which is sort of the opposite of what I'm looking for).